# Why can't I resolve this source conflict in VS 2019?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, visual-studio-2019

There don't appear to be any useful options here to resolve this merge from dev -> main branches. Why? I just want to overwrite whoever changed the main branch incorrectly, but I don't have any option to do that here.

[image: unresolvable resolve conflict listing]

If I right click, I see some options but none of them are useful:
[image: animated gif of the context menu]

Comment: Looks like a bug: have you tried restarting VS2019 and redoing the merge?

Comment: You can use the inbuilt options in Visual Studio to handle the conflicts as shown below. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnU8V.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnU8V.gif)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with it. The issue is a bug at the app level, not a settings change. I've been merging and dealing with conflicts all the time until it just stopped working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disabling the "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities" option works for me, though I'll note that another coworker here with the same exact version doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:**

Microsoft released a fix for this issue, you need to install the recent release from: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads.

---

It's a known issue in Visual Studio 2019, you can read the thread [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/499815/merge-tools-in-resolve-conflicts-not-shown.html).

The official Microsoft solution is:

> We have identified the problem and are preparing a fix. Until the fix
>   can be released, here are a few potential workarounds that may help
>   unblock you.
>
> 1. Launch TFVC operations that may trigger conflict resolution (ex: Get Latest) from Source Control Explorer rather than Solution
>      Explorer. In our testing, the bug repros less frequently from Source
>      Control Explorer entrypoints.
> 2. Try disabling the "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities" option in Tools->Options->Environment->General.

Another workaround you can try is:

Inside the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2019", type the command:

```
tf resolve
```

This will open (from what it looks like) the same window as the one within VS2019, without styling, but the Merge buttons will are present and usable.

When you are done resolving the conflicts in this window, close it and refresh the merge conflict window inside VS2019 to ensure that VS sees the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can't believe that this hasn't been hot-fixed yet.

Comment: @djbyter In case this actually has you stuck, I'm currently getting around this by popping over to VS 2017 to re-do the pull & resolve. They seem to work reasonably well pointing at the same workspace simultaneously.

Comment: Can confirm this is fixed in v16.3.8 for definite.

Answer (score 0):

in the next version the bug is fixed ,update your version of vs,
OR
go to =>
Tools/options/environment/General/
Disabling the "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities"

and  this is fixed.